# What exactly is the queue Abstract Data Type?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, queue

I am not clear on the idea of a Queue. It seems that this term is ambiguous or at least I am confused about it.
While it seems that the most common explanation of a queue (e.g. in wikipedia) is that it is an Abstract Data Type that adheres to the FIFO principle, in practice this term appears to have a broader meaning.
For example, we have

- **Priority Queues** where each item is retrieve according to a priority,
- we have a **stack** which also is a form of inverse queue (LIFO),
- we have **message queues**, which seem to be just a list of items with no
  ordering, there by classifying a simple list as a queue **etc**

So could someone please help me out here on why exactly a queue has so many different meanings?

Comment: queue is a data structure that 'behaves' according to FIFO. The others are not queues. (Excet the message queues, which I am not familiar with the term as an ADT I am afraid)

Comment: Who describes stacks as "inverse queue"? It's a *dual* in a sense (LIFO vs. FIFO), but that's not exactly the most direct relation.

Comment: [ADT - Abstract Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) So since there are different types of queue you will have a different abstract datatype for each of them.

Answer (score 4):

A queue is inherently a data structure following the FIFO principle as its default nature.
Let us treat this queue as a queue in our natural day-to-day lives. Take an example of a queue on the railway station for purchasing tickets.

**Normal queue:** The person standing front-most in the queue gets the ticket, and any new person arriving stands at the end of the queue, waiting for his turn to get a ticket.

**Priority queue:** Suppose you are a VIP standing in the middle of that queue. The ticket vendor immediately notices you, and calls you to the front of the queue to get your tickets, even though its not your turn to purchase. Had you not been important, the queue would have kept playing its usual role, but as soon as any element is considered more important than the other, its picked up, irrespective of its position in the queue. But otherwise, the default nature of the queue remains the same.

**Stack:** Let's not confuse it with the queue at all. The purpose of the stack is inherently different from that of a queue. Take an example of dishes washed and kept in your kitchen, where the last dish washed is the first one to be picked for serving. So, stack and queue have a different role to play in different situations, and should not be confused with each other.

**Message queue:** As is the case with priority queue, the default nature of this queue is that the message that comes first is read first, while the upcoming messages line up in the queue waiting for their turn, unless a message is considered more important than the other and is called to the front of the queue before its usual turn.

So, the default nature of any type of queue remains the same, it continues to follow its FIFO principle unless its made to do otherwise, in special circumstances.

Hope it helps

Comment: 1)But stack and queue is implemented with the same data structures and only the access pattern changes 2)Concerning message queue you specify about the message that comes first is read/stored first but it is not necessarily retrieved first by consumers

Comment: 1) Most of the data structures in the end use arrays as their very basic data structure (taking it at a very low level), as so do stacks and queues. Its the logic that they implement that is important, which can be very different, even though the underlying data structure is similar.

Comment: 2) Message queues as I said, are like priority queues, depending upon how important the message is, they change their order in the queue. Otherwise, considering all messages are equally important, they'll continue to be read/stored in the order in which they arrive, unless requested or prioritized otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a queue models a waiting area where items enter and are eventually selected and removed.  However, different queues can have different [scheduling policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory#Service_disciplines) such as First-In-First-Out (FIFO), Last-In-First-Out (LIFO), Priority, or Random.  For example, queueing theory addresses all of these as queues.

However, in computer science/programming, we typically use the word "queue" to refer specifically to FIFO queues, and use the other words (stack, priority queue, etc.) for the other scheduling policies.  In practice, you should assume FIFO when you hear the word queue, but don't completely rule out the possibility that the speaker might be using the word more generally.

As an aside, similar issues arise with the word "heap" which, depending on context, might refer to a specific implementation of priority queues or to priority queues in general (or, in a mostly unrelated meaning, to an area of memory used for dynamic allocation).

Answer (score -1):

Priority Queue: Its not a queue. Take a look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html it does not implement the Queue interface.

Stack: Its not a queue. Take a look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html it does not implement the Queue interface.

Message queue: I do not know what it is.

Queue: Queue has only one meaning, whoever comes first also get served first.

Queue ADT: It is an interface, meaning it has bunch of functions. Most common ones: add-adds to the end of the line, remove-removes from the beginning of the line. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: The question does not ask for some Java artefact named "Queue", it is even explicitly tagged as language agnostic.

Comment: it was an example, chill